# Why are there different names for same type of data unit?

Tags: c++, types

As far as i know, in c++ on a 32bit compiler, int = __int32 = long = DWORD. But why have so many? Why not just one?

If i were to pick a name, int32 seems most appropriate since there is no confusion there as to what it could be.

Comment: There are so many of what? Also what is `DWORD`?

Comment: @Jefffrey, might be a MS-specific macro... it's basically 2 `short`s.

Comment: `__int32` is not a standard type btw. It's a VS thing.

Comment: @SteveJessop, yup, as my answer mentions :)

Comment: Use cstdint to get guaranteed sizes.

Comment: @SteveJessop, fair point :)

Comment: those were MS specifics, which isn't very "far". You shoul try other compilers and read "farther"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `int` is a pre-C99 type which is guaranteed to be at least 16 bits, but is 32 bits on most modern architectures. (It was originally intended to be the "native" word size, but even on 64-bit architectures it is usually still 32 bits, largely for backwards compatibility reasons.)
- `long` is a pre-C99 type which is guaranteed to be at least 32 bits, but is allowed to be wider. (Few compilers make it longer, even on 64-bit architectures, largely for backwards compatibility reasons.)
- `__int32`/`__int32_t` is a nonstandard typedef which was implemented by many C compilers and runtime libraries, to guarantee a fixed width pre-C99.
- `int32_t` is a C99 type which is guaranteed to be exactly 32 bits.
- `DWORD` is a typedef from the original Windows API which is guaranteed to be exactly 32 bits, from the days when there was no language-defined type of exactly 32 bits.

So basically, the large number of ways to say "32-bit integer" come from how C dragged its feet on standardizing fixed-width types, and from the long tenure of 32-bit processors dominating the field, causing everyone to standardize on 32 bits as the "normal" integer size.

Comment: interesting, history! I guess back in some day an x size variable was a special feature.

Comment: "Few compilers make it longer, even on 64-bit architectures, largely for backwards compatibility reasons." – only true for Windows, AFAIK. On UNIX, LP64 (with 64-bit long) is the norm.

Answer (score 1):

Because of legacy applications.  An `int` doesn't describe how *big* it is at all.  It's an integer.  Big deal.

In the 16-bit era, an `int` was not a `long`.  `DWORD` being a double-word was precise.  A word is known as 2 bytes, and therefore a `DWORD` must be two of them.

`__intXX` are Microsoft specific.

Answer (score 0):

It is because they represent different types which can be translated to different sizes.

1. `int` is a default 'integer' and its size is not specified.
2. `int32' says it is 32 bit (four bytes integer)
3. `long` is a 'longer version integer' which can occupy larger about of bytes. On your 32bit compiler it is still 4 bytes integer. A 'long long' type, which on Windows, as I remember was __int64 was 64bit.
4. `DWORD` is a Microsoft introduced type. It is a 'double word', where word, at that time, meant 'two bytes'

You choice of int32 is good when you *know* that you need 32bit integer.

Comment: "On your 32bit compiler is is 8 bytes integer." -- usually not in C++, 32 bit platforms "normally" have a 32 bit `long`. And (I believe) not in the questioner's compiler which appears to be for Windows.

Comment: @SteveJessop - You may be right. Haven't done in 32bit environment for a long time. I remember transition on 64bit, where long was still 32bit, and then Dell came with 'True64' version where long became 64 bit the same as 'long long'. I am correcting my post.

Answer (score 0):

So, there are lots of different reasons why different projects (e.g Microsoft Windows) uses different types.

Where compilers TODAY are typically 32-bit, this has not always been the case. And there are compilers that are 64-bit.

The term `DWORD` originates from way back when Windows was a 16-bit segmented mode application (many members here have probably never worked on a 16-bit segmented mode environment). It is "two 16-bit words", treated, at least these days, as an unsigned 32-bit value.

The type `int32_t` is defined by the C standard document (and through inheritance, also in C++). It is GUARANTEED to only exist if it is actually exactly 32 bits. On a machine with 36-bit words, there is no `int32_t` (there is a `int32_least_t`, which should exist on all systems that support AT LEAST 32 bits).

`long` is 32 bits in a Windows 32- or 64-bit compiler, but 64-bits in a Linux 64-bit compiler, and 32-bits in a Linux 32-bit compiler. So it's definitely "variable size".

It is also often a good idea to pick your OWN name for types. That is assuming you do care at all - it's also fine to use `int`, `long`, etc, as long as you are not RELYING on them being some size - `for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) x += i;` will work with `i` and `x` being any integer type - the sum is even below 128, so `char` would work. Using `int` here will be fine, since it's likely to be a "fast" type. In some architectures, using `long` may make the code slower - especially in 16-bit architectures where `long` takes up two 16-bit words and needs to be dealt with using (typically) two or more operations for addition and subtraction for example. This can really slow code down in sensitive places.